Converting Natural Earth shapefile data to Winkel-Trippel SVG using proj
I am building an application for highlighting multiple user-specified locations on a map. The first example I'm using is plotting several points around Western/Central Europe. I am using the Natural Earth 1:50m Country shapefile as my base data, and attempting to use that to render an SVG. My initial approach was to dump all of the shapefile data directly into the SVG with no coordinate transposition, and use an SVG viewBox to control the displayed area of the map. The Rust code for this looks something like this:
use std::fmt::Write as _;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Read, Seek, Write as _};
use eyre::Result;
use shapefile::Shape;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut svg = String::new();

    writeln!(
        &mut svg,
        r#"<svg viewbox="-180 -90 360 180" style="transform: scale(1, -1); background-color: lightblue" width="1080" height="540" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">"#,
    )?;

    let world =
        shapefile::Reader::from_path("ne_50m_admin_0_countries/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shp")?;
    draw_countries(&mut svg, world)?;

    writeln!(&mut svg, r#"</svg>"#)?;

    let mut html_file = File::create("fullworld.html")?;
    html_file.write_fmt(format_args!("<!doctype html><html>{svg}</html>"))?;

    println!("Generated {}Kib svg file", svg.len() / 1024);

    Ok(())
}
fn draw_countries(
    svg: &mut String,
    mut world: shapefile::Reader<impl Read + Seek, impl Read + Seek>,
) -> Result<()> {
    for shape_record in world.iter_shapes_and_records() {
        let (shape, _record) = shape_record?;
        if let Shape::Polygon(polygon) = shape {
            for ring in polygon.rings() {
                write!(
                    svg,
                    r#"<polygon stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.025" fill="white" points=""#
                )?;
                for shapefile::Point { x, y } in ring.points() {
                    write!(svg, "{x},{y} ")?;
                }
                writeln!(svg, r#"" />"#)?;
            }
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

This creates a world map that might look ~passable at first glance to an amateur, but zooming in shows that many countries do not have the expected shape.

Germany, for example appears squished when viewed at a close distance.

I also opened the shapefile in QGIS and found that the country shapes are the same there, so I don't think this is an issue with my methodology. In QGIS, if I change the coordinate system to a different projection such as Spherical Winkel Tripel NGS (ESRI:53042), the country shapes look much better (to my eye).

Therefore, I would like to have my application re-project the Natural Earth Shapefile data to SWT so that country borders look the way I expect them to. I tried to accomplish this with proj, but was not successful. The code is 99% the same but the inner for-loop in draw_countries writing out the points now contains an extra transformation step:
let projector = Proj::new_known_crs(&"+proj=natearth", &"+proj=wintri", None).unwrap();
for shapefile::Point { x, y } in ring.points() {
    let (x, y) = projector.convert((*x, *y))?;        
    write!(svg, "{x},{y} ")?;
}

This sadly produces a map that looks worse than the original naïve SVG I created.

Now, I have no doubts that I am doing some Very Silly things here. I'm lacking a lot of GIS knowledge and I recognize that this is a rather naïve way to build a map. Knowing that, is there a straightforward way for me to re-project my Natural Earth shapefile data to Winkel-Tripel, or some other projection that looks more appealing in a close-up map?

Why not reprojecting your shapefile to Winkel-Tripel before using it in your application ?  (https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/training_manual/processing/crs.html#crss-reprojecting)

The ne_50m_admin_0_countries dataset is not in Natural Earth projection. It is in EPSG:4326.
